# The moment estimation of the Heston Model

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, finance, stochastic-differential-equations

I think I get stuck with the Heston SDE as following:

> $X$ is a two dimensional adapted process satisfying the following SDE:
> $$
> \alpha\ ,\beta\ >0\ , b(t,x)=(rx_1,\alpha(\beta-x_2))^T $$
> $$\sigma(x)=
> \left(\begin{matrix}
> x_1\sqrt{x_2}&0 \\
> \sigma\sqrt{x_2}\rho&\sigma\sqrt{x_2}\sqrt{1-\rho^2}\end{matrix}\right)
> $$
> $$dX_t=b(t,X_t)·dt+\sigma(t,X_t)·dB_t,$$ where $2\alpha\beta\geq\sigma^2,\ t\in [0,T], \\ X_0=x\in D= 
>  (0,\infty)^2$.

Then how to prove the following estimates:
$$E\left[\mathop{\sup}\limits_{t\in[0,T]}|X_t|^p \right]\leq C(1+|x|^p),\quad\forall p\geq 1.$$
The constant $C$ is related to $T$(maybe $p$?).
I failed to prove it since the norm of $\sigma$ is not of linear growth! And I have already known that X does not go out of D since $2\alpha\beta\geq\sigma^2$, what I need is only the estimation!

Comment: Presumably, you have some estimation tools at your disposal in whatever course you are following. Can you list them as well in your question?